# Add one more Abstract

Tags: abstract

I need to add one more abstract page in my thesis. I'm using [this model](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis).

I need it to be in Portuguese, so instead of being an "Abstract" is "Resumo". I already tried to copy the definition of the abstract on the Thesis.cls file and change it but it keeps me giving an error.

How can I solve this problem? The idea is to have an abstract in english and another in portuguese.

Comment: Please add an MWE. This is too much guessing and setting up for you. Do you want to have two abstracts? Have you searched this site on how to rename the headings? Do you load `babel` with your language? What have you tried? Where did you fail? Why not showing us the error it is giving you? Thanks.

Comment: You may open the model in overleaf and try directly there. As I said I tried to create a new \newenvironment{abstract} but modifying it to say Resumo but it gives the following error: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.313 \newenvironment{r
                       esumo}

Comment: @user25847: Not everybody uses online editors such as Overleaf (And I am one of those who oppose such editors too). It's again one of the 5 billion thesis templates on the web and we've to excavate the proceedings :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I also don't use an online editor but I thought it was a good idea as people wouldn't have to download the files since it has dependencies.

Comment: @user25847: Well, anyway, I've looked into `Thesis.cls` and the names are hardcoded. This is weird. Do you need two abstracts (an English and a separate Portuguese one) or just one with Portuguese translations?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it is the same one (just translated). I would like to have it in the following page of the english version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant command in `\abstract` is a `\textit{Abstract}`, i.e. it's hardcoded into the abstract.

This can be changed by patching `\textit{Abstract}` to `\textit{\abstractname}`, which is translated into the relevant language representation if `babel` is used.

I've added the lines

```
   \usepackage[portuguese,english]{babel}
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \xpatchcmd{\abstract}{\textit{Abstract}}{\textit{\abstractname}}{}{}
```

to the preamble of `main.tex` (being shipped together with `Thesis.cls` as an example file)

and `\selectlanguage{portuguese}` just before `\abstract` and after it switched back to `\selectlanguage{english}`.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.43 (17/5/14)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original authors:
% Steven Gunn 
% http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/
% and
% Sunil Patel
% http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Note:
% Make sure to edit document variables in the Thesis.cls file
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)

\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored

\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} % Use the natbib reference package - read up on this to edit the reference style; if you want text (e.g. Smith et al., 2012) for the in-text references (instead of numbers), remove 'numbers' 
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying
\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this


%%%%%%%%%%%%% My additions 


\usepackage[portuguese,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\abstract}{\textit{Abstract}}{\textit{\abstractname}}{}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% My additions end here for the preamble 



\begin{document}

\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages

\setstretch{1.3} % Line spacing of 1.3

% Define the page headers using the FancyHdr package and set up for one-sided printing
\fancyhead{} % Clears all page headers and footers
\rhead{\thepage} % Sets the right side header to show the page number
\lhead{} % Clears the left side page header

\pagestyle{fancy} % Finally, use the "fancy" page style to implement the FancyHdr headers

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % New command to make the lines in the title page

% PDF meta-data
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\ttitle}}
\hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\textsc{\LARGE \univname}\\[1.5cm] % University name
\textsc{\Large Doctoral Thesis}\\[0.5cm] % Thesis type

\HRule \\[0.4cm] % Horizontal line
{\huge \bfseries \ttitle}\\[0.4cm] % Thesis title
\HRule \\[1.5cm] % Horizontal line

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{\authornames} % Author name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
\href{http://www.jamessmith.com}{\supname} % Supervisor name - remove the \href bracket to remove the link  
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]

\large \textit{A thesis submitted in fulfilment of the requirements\\ for the degree of \degreename}\\[0.3cm] % University requirement text
\textit{in the}\\[0.4cm]
\groupname\\\deptname\\[2cm] % Research group name and department name

{\large \today}\\[4cm] % Date
%\includegraphics{Logo} % University/department logo - uncomment to place it

\vfill
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DECLARATION PAGE
%   Your institution may give you a different text to place here
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\Declaration{

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

I, \authornames, declare that this thesis titled, '\ttitle' and the work presented in it are my own. I confirm that:

\begin{itemize} 
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] This work was done wholly or mainly while in candidature for a research degree at this University.
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where any part of this thesis has previously been submitted for a degree or any other qualification at this University or any other institution, this has been clearly stated.
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where I have consulted the published work of others, this is always clearly attributed.
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where I have quoted from the work of others, the source is always given. With the exception of such quotations, this thesis is entirely my own work.
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] I have acknowledged all main sources of help.
\item[\tiny{$\blacksquare$}] Where the thesis is based on work done by myself jointly with others, I have made clear exactly what was done by others and what I have contributed myself.\\
\end{itemize}

Signed:\\
\rule[1em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line for the signature

Date:\\
\rule[1em]{25em}{0.5pt} % This prints a line to write the date
}

\clearpage % Start a new page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   QUOTATION PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers or footers for the following pages

\null\vfill % Add some space to move the quote down the page a bit

\textit{``Thanks to my solid academic training, today I can write hundreds of words on virtually any topic without possessing a shred of information, which is how I got a good job in journalism."}

\begin{flushright}
Dave Barry
\end{flushright}

\vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\null % Add some space at the bottom to position the quote just right

\clearpage % Start a new page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\addtotoc{Abstract} % Add the "Abstract" page entry to the Contents

%%%%% Another addition --> switch to Portuguese
\selectlanguage{portuguese}
\abstract{\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

The Thesis Abstract is written here (and usually kept to just this page). The page is kept centered vertically so can expand into the blank space above the title too\ldots
}
%%%%%%%%%%% Switch back to English

\selectlanguage{english}


\clearpage % Start a new page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setstretch{1.3} % Reset the line-spacing to 1.3 for body text (if it has changed)

\acknowledgements{\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

The acknowledgements and the people to thank go here, don't forget to include your project advisor\ldots
}
\clearpage % Start a new page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\pagestyle{fancy} % The page style headers have been "empty" all this time, now use the "fancy" headers as defined before to bring them back

\lhead{\emph{Contents}} % Set the left side page header to "Contents"
\tableofcontents % Write out the Table of Contents

\lhead{\emph{List of Figures}} % Set the left side page header to "List of Figures"
\listoffigures % Write out the List of Figures

\lhead{\emph{List of Tables}} % Set the left side page header to "List of Tables"
\listoftables % Write out the List of Tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABBREVIATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage % Start a new page

\setstretch{1.5} % Set the line spacing to 1.5, this makes the following tables easier to read

\lhead{\emph{Abbreviations}} % Set the left side page header to "Abbreviations"
\listofsymbols{ll} % Include a list of Abbreviations (a table of two columns)
{
\textbf{LAH} & \textbf{L}ist \textbf{A}bbreviations \textbf{H}ere \\
%\textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{W}hat (it) \textbf{S}tands \textbf{F}or \\
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PHYSICAL CONSTANTS/OTHER DEFINITIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage % Start a new page

\lhead{\emph{Physical Constants}} % Set the left side page header to "Physical Constants"

\listofconstants{lrcl} % Include a list of Physical Constants (a four column table)
{
Speed of Light & $c$ & $=$ & $2.997\ 924\ 58\times10^{8}\ \mbox{ms}^{-\mbox{s}}$ (exact)\\
% Constant Name & Symbol & = & Constant Value (with units) \\
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SYMBOLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage % Start a new page

\lhead{\emph{Symbols}} % Set the left side page header to "Symbols"

\listofnomenclature{lll} % Include a list of Symbols (a three column table)
{
$a$ & distance & m \\
$P$ & power & W (Js$^{-1}$) \\
% Symbol & Name & Unit \\

& & \\ % Gap to separate the Roman symbols from the Greek

$\omega$ & angular frequency & rads$^{-1}$ \\
% Symbol & Name & Unit \\
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEDICATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setstretch{1.3} % Return the line spacing back to 1.3

\pagestyle{empty} % Page style needs to be empty for this page

\dedicatory{For/Dedicated to/To my\ldots} % Dedication text

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - CHAPTERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering

\pagestyle{fancy} % Return the page headers back to the "fancy" style

% Include the chapters of the thesis as separate files from the Chapters folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the chapters

\input{Chapters/Chapter1}
%\input{Chapters/Chapter2} 
%\input{Chapters/Chapter3}
%\input{Chapters/Chapter4} 
%\input{Chapters/Chapter5} 
%\input{Chapters/Chapter6} 
%\input{Chapters/Chapter7} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - APPENDICES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following 'chapters' are Appendices

% Include the appendices of the thesis as separate files from the Appendices folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the Appendices

\input{Appendices/AppendixA}
%\input{Appendices/AppendixB}
%\input{Appendices/AppendixC}

\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2em}} % Add a gap in the Contents, for aesthetics

\backmatter

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\label{Bibliography}

\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}} % Change the page header to say "Bibliography"

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography

\bibliography{Bibliography} % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've marked changes in this document with long `%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%` lines

Answer (score 3):

Using an updated version of the template, this is much easier:

[image: texsxMdtTemplate]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Masters/Doctoral Thesis 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.1 (2/9/15)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Version 2.0 major modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% Original authors:
% Steven Gunn  (http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/)
% Sunil Patel (http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
portuguese,
english, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
headsepline,
nohyperref
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{palatino} 

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography


\thesistitle{Thesis Title} 
\supervisor{Dr. James \textsc{Smith}} 
\examiner{} 
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy} 
\author{John \textsc{Smith}} 

\university{University of Duckburg} 
\department{Department of applied Dancing} 
\group{A nice group} 
\faculty{Jazz dance} 

\newcaptionname{portuguese}{\byname}{por}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}
{\selectlanguage{portuguese}
\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext
\end{abstract}
}
\end{document}
```

Note: That abstract page might not even make any sense in portuguese.