# Multiple abstracts with same page layout but in different languages

Tags: languages, abstract

I'd like to have two abstracts in different languages at two pages(one in native language, other in english). I have used the answer in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253236/add-one-more-abstract) which is useful but my problem is, I have my degree name, dept name etc. in the abstract page; so I also need to convert them as well. The environment is as following in Thesis.cls file;

```
\newenvironment{abstract}
{
  \btypeout{Abstract Page}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \null\vfil
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    {\normalsize\textbf{ \UNIVNAME} \par} % University name in capitals
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize\textbf{ÖZET} \par} % ÖZET means ABSTRACT in turkish.
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \facname \par} % Faculty name
    {\normalsize \deptname \par} % Department name
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \degreename\par} % Degree name
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize\bf \ttitle \par} % Thesis title
    \medskip
    {\normalsize \authornames \par} % Author name
    \bigskip
  \end{center}
}
```

How to implement the same page layout but in english for the 2. abstract page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh no, please don't use that template.

Comment: Sh*t why? It's too late now.

Comment: Well, please ignore my comment then. Please share with us where you got the template from (link) and which version you are using (should be at the top of main). Maybe the following will help you as well: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl#comment-2671646496

Comment: Since you had to put in Özet manually, i guess you are using `Thesis.cls` from sharelatex, or Sunils original, or a version from overleaf/l-templates that was, in the meantime, updated almost a year ago.

Comment: It's the one I use https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl#.V06lopN969Z

Comment: See, old version ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all the stuff from the `\thispagestyle` line down to `\end{center}` and copy/paste it after the abstract in you main language. 
Substitute all the `\UNIVNAME` stuff (and others) with the strings in your other language. Be sure to use the correct babel switch to get the hyphenation patterns for the other language.