# using thesis template in french

Tags: templates, languages, thesis

I have a latex thesis template, written in english. I would like to use it in french but i didn't translate the defined layout like the word "chapter", " List of ...".

Have you any idea how to translate the layout.

Comment: Do you use the `babel` package? Then pass the option `french` to it. Otherwise we definitely need to see your code (MWE).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, when i use \usepackage[french]{babel}, i get this error : ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package babel.

Comment: In that case you need to show us an MWE and your template. But if it already loads `babel` it can be (it need not be at all) hard to get it to use French. Maybe the developer did not intend the template to be used with other languages.

Comment: I didn't add the code but this is the URL of the template : http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis.

Comment: @FatmaBelabed somewhere in the template files there should be a line calling the `babel` package where you can probably just add French.

Comment: Put french in the documentclass options.

Comment: Search the net for the mdt unofficial quick guide and you will find a probably helpful github site. There is also already a Q/A for that on TeX.SX

Comment: *"english or ngerman is passed down to package babel. babel takes care of proper hyphenation. The language you use also changes predefined strings (for example Contents in english and Inhaltsverzeichnis in german). You can use any langauge known to babel, but might need to add strings for the language you are using."* (from [MDT-Quick-Manual](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual)) and [Add one more Abstract](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276235/37907)

Comment: Is there any news here? There was no response to my suggestions.